# Formula for powering a matrix not working for all matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I'm currently learning about matrices and was asked to show that this formula works for powers of $M$. 
$$M^n = nM-(n-1)I$$
Where $M$ is the matrix (show below), $n$ is the exponent an $I$ is the identity matrix.

$$
M = 
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & -1\\ 
4 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I then tried this on other matrices such as 
$$
M = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
4 & 5 & 6 \\
7 & 8 & 9 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

However I found that the formula did not work. Why is it so and under what constraints will this formula work?

Comment: The formula doesn't work for all matrices because the formula isn't true for all matrices. It's only true for matrices whose minimal polynomial divides $x^n - nx + (n-1)$.

Comment: @AshwathRabindranath Could you please explain what the minimal polynomial is?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_%28linear_algebra%29

Comment: @AshwathRabindranath I don't understand quite a few terms that article uses. Do you have a simpler explanation?

Comment: The point really is that there's no reason for you to expect it to be true for a general matrix. My characterization is essentially saying that it's true only in the special cases where it's true. There's nothing better that can be said.